# Strange behaviour on redefining \contentsname

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I'm using `amsart` class.

I know how to change the value of `\contentsname` (default is *Contents*). We can make use of `\def` or `\renewcommand`.

But I'd like to know why it does not work if I use those commands on preamble?

I only can change its value using, for example, `\renewcommand\contentsname{List of Abstracts}` after `\begin{document}`.

**Why??**

Comment: `\documentclass{amsart}\def\contentsname{foo}\begin{document}bar\end{document}` compiles without mishap, here. Same with `\renewcommand`. Can you post some minimal code?

Comment: Are you using `babel`? I guess so. Please, make a minimal example. Also look for `\addto` and `babel`.

Comment: @egreg, you're right. Removing `babel` solve the problem. Thanks a lot. If you wish, answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a standard feature. At the beginnings, most of the fixed tags were harcoded into `lplain.tex`, the main file for the LaTeX kernel or in the class files (at the time “style files”). When European users started using LaTeX with different languages than English, the need for translating those fixed words emerged.

The first versions of `babel` patched several commands from the kernel or the class files. When LaTeX2e was released, for every fixed word a command was defined, so for `babel` it was easier hooking into LaTeX by changing the meaning of those commands. Thus, for Italian, it was easy to define `\contentsname` to mean “Indice” and not “Contents”.

The `babel` package stores the fixed tags for a language in the command `\captions<language>`. For Italian we have something like

```
\def\captionsitalian{%
  \def\prefacename{Prefazione}%
  \def\refname{Riferimenti bibliografici}%
  \def\abstractname{Sommario}%
  \def\bibname{Bibliografia}%
  \def\chaptername{Capitolo}%
  ...
}
```

When `babel` switches from one language to another, it executes the corresponding `\captions<language>` command. The first switch happens when `\begin{document}` is being executed. Of course, if `babel` is not loaded, nothing happens and the default fixed tags for English are used.

Coming to your problem, you have two strategies:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{List of abstracts}

\begin{document}
```

without `babel`. If, however, one of your abstracts is, say, in French, you'd like to load French and English with `babel`. The redefinition above would not work, because of the execution of `\captionsenglish` at `\begin{document}`. Here's the correct workaround:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % French wants it
\usepackage[french,english]{babel} % English is the default

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{List of abstracts}}

\begin{document}
```

In this way, the redefinition of `\contentsname` is appendend to the list of commands executed by `\captionsenglish`. So, any time you load `babel`, a change to a fixed tag must be made with `\addto\captions<language>`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this public talk. As always, now it is clear when we learn the theory behind the scene. So I suppose that `\addto` adds the `\renew....` at the end of the command `\captionsenglish` to overwrite the `contentsname`, right?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, it just appends the contents of the argument to the meaning of `\captionsenglish`.

Answer (score 12):

As stated by egreg, using babel makes `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{New Contents Name}` stop working correctly. If you dont wantto use `\addto` solution, I find using hooks are a simple workaround.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{New Contents Name}}
```

I had the same trouble just now, and found this method by intuition. (my first answer here (: )