# Problems with changing toc name

Tags: table-of-contents, babel

I need to change the table of contents name (into Russian). I have already read answers to similar questions 
[How to change the title of ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc)
and
[Strange behaviour on redefining \contentsname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153182/strange-behaviour-on-redefining-contentsname), but the following code doesn't work (table of contents titled as 'Contents').

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Содержание}}
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183435/120578 ... It is a duplicate... (Some times the non-accepted answers providing the solution that works in our case)

Comment: Oh ... I think that you are using the wrong order in the babel loading of languages (english is your default this way)... Or you should define  \captionsenglish instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Содержание}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

This also works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Содержание}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

Your problem was that you was starting with english as the default language and you had changed the `\contentsname` for russian language.

The default language by `babel` package is the one loaded last in its options.

Comment: Thanks, indeed both methods work. I tried combination \usepackage[english, russian]{babel} but compilation failed and I had the error 'Command \CYRF is unavailable in encoding OT1'. I think it's because previously I tried to compile \usepackage[russian,english]{babel}.

Comment: Happy that worked for you... Have a nice night.